# 301 Redirect removing .html extension

Tags: redirect

Hi I need to 301 redirect the following-

http://www.satellites.co.uk/forums/tags/freesat.html

to

http://www.satellites.co.uk/forums/tags/forums/freesat/

freesat.html could be any file name depending on the search term.

The .htaccess file is in the root folder and we require the trailing slash.

Thanks
Chris.

Comment: Can you tag the web server you are using